# How do I pronounce 也許可以使表達更有條理

Tags: pronunciation

I know the individual pronunciation in each word in the sentence 也許可以使表達更有條理, but when put together I'm confused by the string of third tones in the beginning: 也許可以使表

也許: 2-3

可以使表: 2-3-2-3 or 2-2-2-3 or something else?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My treatment is 也许--可以使--表达，2-3--2-2-3--3-2

There is a slight pause after 许 and 使.

Answer (score 0):

两个3, 第一个要读2, 如: 你好（ní hǎo）、处理（chú lǐ）、可以（ké yǐ）。只是读音上，拼音时还是三声的

Comment: This does not answer the question! While what you write is true, the question is about a sentence containing more than two consecutive third tones. Tone sandhi in these cases is more complicated than you make it sound, and knowing how bisyllabic words behave in general is not enough.